# imshow error with OpenCV, Qt & Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu

I have a problem with a basic program in Qt 5.3, this is the code:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("/home/isaac/lena.jpg");
    if(!inputImage.empty()) cv::imshow("Prueba",inputImage);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**displayimage.pro**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = displayimage
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

This is the output error:

```
Starting /home/isaac/workspace/Qt Creator/Prueba/build-displayimage-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_GCC_64bit-Release/displayimage...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/isaac/workspace/Qt Creator/Prueba/build-displayimage-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_GCC_64bit-Release/displayimage crashed
```

I just read an image and show but does not work and don't know why . If I comment imshow the program works.

Comment: you probably have other debug errors.. post them. Also you probably need to `waitKey(0);` after `imshow`.

Comment: I added this and the program still show same errors , I have no other errors only this.

Comment: print out the img dimension just after imread. `imputImage.rows` and `inputImage.cols`

Comment: If I uncommented imshow the output is the same error but if I comment imshow the output is: Starting /home/isaac/workspace/Qt Creator/Prueba/build-displayimage-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_GCC_64bit-Release/displayimage...
Rows: 512, Cols: 512

Comment: A common cause of this problem is linking to debug libraries in release mode, or vice versa. Make sure this isn't the case.

Comment: probably the issue it that imshow doesn't integrate well in Qt. You'd better try converting you Mat in a QImage and show it in a QLabel

Comment: `QImage imgIn= QImage((uchar*) img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);`

Comment: Have you tried to move imshow outside the constructor and did that help?

Comment: cv::waitKey(0); gives the same error so the error is not only of imshow()

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on my machine (Ubuntu 15.04, OpenCV 3.0.0, Qt). Also no difference whether you put a `cv::waitKey(0);` after `cv::imshow` or not.
Have you enabled `WITH_QT` while compiling OpenCV?

Comment: I think yes, but I'm not sure. What would it take to rebuild?

Comment: I'm compiling with WITH_QT activate and get the same error.

Comment: Have you removed all old versions on your computer? I got stuck on that problem quite a long time because Qt is not (always) using the newest installed version.
What can you figure out while debugging? Have you checked your library and include paths (are they existing on your system)?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.
I have solved deleting the build folder and rebuild using this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
```